# mime fonts problems updating Apache from 2.2 to 2.4.25

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, apache-2.4, httpd.conf

After updating my Apache Windows server, my website is not showing correctly fonts (eot, svg, ttf, woff).

I have updated from 2.2 to 2.4.25 adding a SSL certificate also. Everything is running well except the fonts

In the past I was using this "hack" on my .conf file
AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot
AddType font/ttf .ttf
AddType font/otf .otf

But now it is not working anymore. I am not sure it is because Apache new syntax or by new SSL.

Can you help please?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

From your browser or the command line did you try to retrieve one of our font file, and if so, have you checked its `Content-Type` header value and is it the correct MIME type? If not, it probably means you need to put back your hack inside the Apache configuration.

Comment: thx. Yes I can download every font like https://domain.com/font.ttf so it seems to work... Safari shows well the fonts... Chrome or Firefox don't show. In fact, this hack was for Mozilla browser, and it was used firstly on 2011 (apache 2.2.19). Something has changed now with apache 2.4.45